# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') with dropdown select in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm trying to get my react chops up and build a simple site with a select dropdown which should route to a URL when selected. However I'm getting this error.  Or if there's a better way to do this with hooks, I am all ears :). Thanks

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
DropDown.onChange
src/components/Dropdown.js:10
   7 | 
   8 | class DropDown extends Component {
   9 |   onChange = (e) => {
> 10 |     this.props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`);
  11 |   }
  12 | 
  13 |   render() {
```

Below is my code

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import '../App.css'
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import { BrowserRouter, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

   class DropDown extends Component {
   onChange = (e) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`);
  }

   render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="pests">Choose a pest:</label>
        <select onChange={this.onChange}>
          <option value="ants">Ants</option>
          <option value="wasps">Wasps</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DropDown;
```

Here's my router code

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      {/* <Navbar/> */}
      <Header />
      <NavbarBasic />
      <Dropdown />
      {/* These are the main routes and subpages */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/pests-we-treat' element={<Pests />} />
        <Route path='/services' element={<Services />} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path='/ants' element={<Ants />} />
        <Route path='/wasps' element={<Wasps />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Class component to functional component

Transform your class component in a functional componente and import **useHistory** like this :

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
...
let history = useHistory();
history.push(`/${e.target.value}`);
```

## Another way, using JS

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    // import { BrowserRouter, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

    class DropDown extends Component {

      onChange = (e) => {
        // this.props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`);
        window.location.href = `/${e.target.value}`;
      }

      render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="pests">Choose a pest:</label>
              <select onChange={this.onChange}>
                <option value="ants">Ants</option>
                <option value="wasps">Wasps</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default DropDown;
```

## Another method mixing class component and React Hooks

dropdownRouter.tsx

```
    import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

    export default function DropdownPush(path: string) {
      let history = createBrowserHistory();
      history.push(`/${path}`);
    }
```

OR

```
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

    export default function DropdownPush(path: string) {
       const history = useHistory();
       history.push(`/${path}`);
    }
```

OR if you are using v6 react-router-dom useHistory() was replaced by useNavigate()

```
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

    export default function DropdownPush(path: string) {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      navigate(`/${path}`);
    }
```

dropdown.tsx

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import DropdownPush from './dropdownRouter';

    class DropDown extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      onChange = (e) => {
        // this.props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`);
        
        // JS redirect method
        // window.location.href = `/${e.target.value}`;
        
        // Using Hook
        DropdownPush(e.target.value);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="pests">Choose a pest: </label>
            <select onChange={this.onChange}>
              <option value="ants">Ants</option>
              <option value="wasps">Wasps</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default DropDown;
```

Comment: OP is using a class component. Hooks are certainly a better way to do this, but they're not going to work here without refactoring the whole component.

Comment: I suggested one solution trying to help. Do you really think that is a good idea set down ?

Comment: As I said, hooks are the better way to solve this problem, but they are not going to work for OP. Your code block is therefore incomplete, unless you're about to refactor OP's whole component?

Comment: Thanks, if you have any tips on how to do this in hooks, I'm game. I'm trying it but still can't get it just yet.

Comment: @erics15 you can use "window.location", sounds a good options for you ? I updated the answer.

Comment: If you want to use Router I´ll suggest another way, so let me know.

Comment: @Olavo thank you so much, I'm really trying to learn this stuff (the JS works thanks!) so if you have a Router idea, please share if you'd like.

Comment: Amazing @erics15. Happy to help you. Mark as solved to help others dude. Cheers !!

Comment: @Olavo, I marked it as so.  Any idea on how to keep the dropdown selected to the page navigated to?

Comment: I added an idea @erics15. Hope to be useful for you.

Comment: @Olavo, thanks. So close, it changes the URL but doesn't reload the page to the correct one :)

Comment: @erics15 I added a suggestion to v6. Check it out!

Comment: @olavo thank you - had to convert to a functional component but's screaming at me that there's a problem using the hook due to multiple versions of react or something which doesn't make sense. I'm not using typescript either just yet (taking things slow ;))

Comment: lol sometimes we just don't know what happens. Cheers my friend!

Answer (score -1):

I expect you want to wrap your `Dropdown` component in the [`withRouter` higher-order component](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter). That would usually happen in the export:

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class DropDown extends Component {
  // ...
}

export default withRouter(Dropdown);
```

The alternative way to access `history` is to use the [`useHistory` hook](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory), and the docs contain a good example of how to use it.